# How can I set up a max value for dynamic inputs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I have vue form with dynamic inputs.
1st. user register total shares amount in form
2nd. he start issue this total amount to shareholders partially by adding dynamic inputs as much as he need
 
3rd he submit the form.
 
My task is to avoid overissue.

I can' figure out how to avoid issue share to shareholders more than it registred in total/

```
Ex:
totalSharesAmount = 100
shareholder[0] - shares_amount = 50 
shareholder[1] - shares_amount = 20 //70 total
shareholder[2] - shares_amount = 30 //100 total. can't be more than 100
```

My data:

```
data() {
return {
    totatSharesAmount: 100
    shareholders: [{share_amount: '', share_price: ''}]
    }
}
```

My validate method (computed) and here I need help:

```
sharesToFounders() {
    return {
      required: true,
      max_value: this.totalSharesAmount - this.shareholder['shares_amount'] //need help here
   }
}
```

Comment: You should probably describe the behavior you're looking for in more detail. Are you saying you want new inputs to appear until the user has used all the points by filling them in?

Comment: @RoyJ Ok, I made some changes in my post, hope it's better describe the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve it: keep track of the current total, and on input, use a validator method to either allow the user's change, or prevent it.

Markup:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="row"><span>Total:</span><input type="number" v-model="totalPoints"></div>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in foundersPoints" class="row">
    <input type="number" v-on:input="updateValue(index)" v-model="foundersPoints[index].points_amount"><span v-if="foundersPoints[index].alert" class="alert">{{foundersPoints[index].alert}} <button v-on:click="dismissAlert(index)">OK</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Validator method:

```
updateValue(idx) {
    let value;
    if (this.tempSum > this.totalPoints) {
    const overage = this.totalPoints - this.tempSum;
    value = Number(this.foundersPoints[idx].points_amount) + overage;
  } else {
    value = Number(this.foundersPoints[idx].points_amount);
  }
  this.foundersPoints[idx].points_amount = value;
},
```

Current total (a computed property) used to keep track of the :

```
computed: {
  tempSum() {
    const pointsAmounts = this.foundersPoints.map(item => Number(item.points_amount));
    return pointsAmounts.reduce((acc, t) => acc + Number(t), 0);
  }
},
```

See it in action in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/vu508Lgc/

This does not handle the case where a user reduces the total points allowed. (User had total = 60 and then set each of the three points values to 20. If the user then changes the total to 40, what happens to the inputs that add up to 60?)

Answer (score 1):

You need a computed to keep track of remaining points. You need a function to add elements to your array when there are points remaining. You need to hook up a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) to call that function. The snippet below does that.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      totalPoints: 100,
      foundersPoints: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addPoint() {
      this.foundersPoints.push({
        points_amount: null,
        point_price: null
      });
    }
  },
  watch: {
    remainingPoints: {
      handler(v) {
        if (v > 0 && this.pointValues.every((v) => v > 0)) {
          this.addPoint();
        }
        if (v <= 0 || isNaN(v)) {
          // Remove any zeros, probably just the last entry
          this.foundersPoints = this.foundersPoints.filter((o) => o.points_amount > 0);
        }
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    pointValues() {
      return this.foundersPoints.map((o) => o.points_amount);
    },
    remainingPoints() {
      const used = this.pointValues.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

      return this.totalPoints - used;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
:invalid {
  border: solid red 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="p in foundersPoints">
    <input v-model.number="p.points_amount" type="number" min="1" :max="p.points_amount + remainingPoints">
  </div>
  <div>Remaining shares: {{remainingPoints}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh that looks like what I'm looking for! I'm gonna try it out now. thanks.